# Problems data binding Listbox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listbox

My question is how to attach the data file to the XAML?
so that the data Name, Images , Age displayed ListBox.

There is a class Person:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Images { get; set; }
public string Age { get; set; }
```

There is an xml file UsersList
(about 100 users)
xml file constantly edited

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<users>
  <user name="Bill Gates">  
    <images>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558109954561679360/j1f9DiJi.jpeg</images>
    <age>48</age>
  </user>
  <user name="Larry Page">
    <images>http://www.siliconbeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/page.jpg</images>
    <age>42</age>
  </user>
</users>
```

XAML

```
<ListBox  x:Name="ListBox" Margin="36,10,273,0" >
            <ListBox.DataContext>
                <user:Person/>
            </ListBox.DataContext>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Images}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

code-behind

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load();
        }
    public void Load()
        {
            Person user = new Person();
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("UsersList");

            XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

            foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
            {


                if (xnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
                    if (attr != null)
                        user.Name = attr.Value;

                }

                foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
                {

                    if (childnode.Name == "images")
                    {
                        user.Images = childnode.InnerText;

                    }

                    if (childnode.Name == "age")
                    {
                        user.Age = childnode.InnerText;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the code below.

```
class MainWindow:System.Windows.Window 
{
    List<Person> lstPerson;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lstPerson = new List<Person>();
        Load();
    }
    public void Load()
    {

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("UsersList");

        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
        {
            Person user = new Person();

            if (xnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
            {
                XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
                if (attr != null)
                    user.Name = attr.Value;

            }

            foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
            {

                if (childnode.Name == "images")
                {
                    user.Images = childnode.InnerText;

                }

                if (childnode.Name == "age")
                {
                    user.Age = childnode.InnerText;
                }
            }

            lstPerson.Add(user)

        }

        ListBox.itemsSource= lstPerson

    }
}
```

And Below is the Xaml part

```
<ListBox  x:Name="ListBox" Margin="36,10,273,0" >            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Source="{Binding Images}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

> For Image source binding

You can not provide http address as image source. Here you need a converter which download image from web create image and return to source.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `ListBox.ItemsSource` to an observable list of persons (`ObservableCollection<Person>`) and implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx%20%60INotifyPropertyChanged%60) interface on your `Person` class.

`Person user = new Person();` should be `ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();`

Then you have to create a new `Person` object inside the foreach loop and add it to the persons list like this:

```
persons.Add(person);
```

And if you don't need to update your list if you change a property of a person, then you don't really need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: The correct name is `ObservableCollection` not `ObservableList`, I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, the ListBox's `ItemsSource` must be set, not its `DataContext`. If you only set the DataContext, you would also need something like `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the *ItemsSource* property of the ListBox to an `IEnumerable<Person>`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListBox.ItemsSource = Load();
}

public List<Person> Load()
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("UsersList");

    XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

    List<Person> users = new List<Person>();
    foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
    {
        Person user = new Person();
        if (xnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
        {
            XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
            if (attr != null)
                user.Name = attr.Value;
        }

        foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
        {

            if (childnode.Name == "images")
            {
                user.Images = childnode.InnerText;

            }

            if (childnode.Name == "age")
            {
                user.Age = childnode.InnerText;
            }
        }
        users.Add(user);
    }

    return users;
}
```